# UIButton to open Facebook app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

im trying to make a button that will exit my app and open up the facebook app (if available) to my apps profile. And I cant figure out how I would do this.

Comment: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get your button to call the following method when clicked:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<your_profile_id>"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }

}
```

If the Facebook app is installed on your device, then it should open to your profile.

Comment: same problem as with the above answer. it only displays white.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook app on the iPhone conforms to the fb:// URL pattern, fb://profile/{profile id number} will open the Facebook app to the specified profile id number

You could make your button open the URL specific to your apps profile.

Comment: thanks this is just what i needed but i cant get anything to display. It opens the facebook app but its just a white screen maybe im getting the formatting wrong could you possible give me an example or clarify. Thanks this is just what i needed.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems hit or miss. I have tested with some profile IDs of my friends and it brings up a blank page for some but not for others... Interesting, possibly a bug with the facebook app. Maybe you should present a UIWebView in a modal view. Not the same experience you seem to be looking for but a possible substitute...